# How can I include add, edit and delete button to d3 tree layout nodes?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have generated a tree structure using d3.js which looks like this
[image]

But I want to include add,edit and delete button so that tree can be managed dynamically. 
Here is one more picture of what I want to include.

[image]

Code looks like this:

```
     var treeData =data;
            console.log(treeData)



            var margin = {
                    top: 20,
                    right: 120,
                    bottom: 20,
                    left: 120
                },
                width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
                height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

            var i = 0;



            var tree = d3.layout.tree()
                .size([height, width]);

            var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
                .projection(function(d) { return [/*width -*/ d.y + 30, d.x + 25]; });


            var svg = d3.select("#tree").append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

            root = treeData[0];

            update(root);

            function update(source) {

                // Compute the new tree layout.
                var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
                    links = tree.links(nodes);

                // Normalize for fixed-depth.
                nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = width-(d.depth * 180); });

                // Declare the nodes…
                var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
                    .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

                // Enter the nodes.
                var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
                    .attr("class", "node")
                    .attr("transform", function(d) {
                        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

 /*               nodeEnter.append("circle")
                /!*nodeEnter.append("new-div")*!/
                    .attr("r", 20)
                    .style("fill", "#fff");*/


                nodeEnter.append("rect")
                    .attr("width", 100)
                    .attr("height", 40)
                    .attr("stroke", "black")
                    .attr("stroke-width", 1)
                    .style("fill", function (d) {
                        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
                    });

           /*     nodeEnter.append("text")
                    .attr("y", function(d) {
                        return d.children || d._children ? -18 : 18; })
                    .attr("dy", ".35em")
                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                    .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
                    .style("fill-opacity", 1);*/

                nodeEnter.append("text")
                    .attr("x", 100 / 2)
                    .attr("y", 40 / 2)
                    .attr("dy", ".35em")
                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                    .text(function (d) {
                        return d.name;
                    });
                // Declare the links…
                var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
                    .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

                // Enter the links.
                link.enter().insert("path", "g")
                    .attr("class", "link")
                    .attr("d", diagonal);

            }
```

In html file I just have

```
<div id="tree">
</div>
```

Comment: just do this with html and on the button clicks run the functions that edit the layout : add, delete edit etc

Comment: @thisOneGuy donot have much code inside my html. Let me update the question with code.

Comment: I basically want these buttons on every node.

Comment: Ahh sorry my bad I thought you wanted them separate. So instead of just creating a rectangle for each node you're going to want a rectangle holding the add, edit and delete buttons correct ?

Answer (score 1):

I found a fiddle online and edited it to show you a basic version of what you want : http://jsfiddle.net/reko91/JnNwu/729/

Here is the main code :

```
var nodeWidth = 300, nodeHeight = 100;
var buttonWidth = nodeWidth/3;

//container
nodeEnter.append("rect")
 .attr('class','buttonContainer')
        .attr("width", nodeWidth)
        .attr("height", nodeHeight)
        .style("fill", 'lightsteelblue')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,'+(-nodeHeight/2)+')');
//buttonAdd
    nodeEnter.append("rect")
    .attr('class','addButton')
        .attr("width", buttonWidth)
        .attr("height", nodeHeight/1.5)
        .style("fill",'white')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + nodeHeight/6 + ','+(-nodeHeight/2 + nodeHeight/6)+')')
        .on('click', function(d){
        console.log('addButton')
        })
        ;

      //buttonDelete
    nodeEnter.append("rect")
    .attr('class','deleteButton')
        .attr("width", buttonWidth)
        .attr("height", nodeHeight/1.5)
        .style("fill",'red')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (nodeWidth - buttonWidth- nodeHeight/6 )+ ','+(-nodeHeight/2 + nodeHeight/6)+')')
        .on('click', function(d){
        console.log('deleteButton')
        })
        ;
```

What I have done here is, for every node I have appended a container which holds both the add and delete button (you can easily add the edit). On click, they console log their corresponding functions. So the add logs `addButton` and so on.

Now to implement the proper functionality of each button :)

```js
var json = 
{
    "name": "Base",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "Type A",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Section 1",
                    "children": [
                        {"name": "Child 1"},
                        {"name": "Child 2"},
                        {"name": "Child 3"}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Section 2",
                    "children": [
                        {"name": "Child 1"},
                        {"name": "Child 2"},
                        {"name": "Child 3"}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Type B",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Section 1",
                    "children": [
                        {"name": "Child 1"},
                        {"name": "Child 2"},
                        {"name": "Child 3"}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Section 2",
                    "children": [
                        {"name": "Child 1"},
                        {"name": "Child 2"},
                        {"name": "Child 3"}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

var width = 700;
var height = 650;
var maxLabel = 150;
var duration = 500;
var radius = 5;
    
var i = 0;
var root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + maxLabel + ",0)");

root = json;
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

root.children.forEach(collapse);

function update(source) 
{
    // Compute the new tree layout.
    var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse();
    var links = tree.links(nodes);

    // Normalize for fixed-depth.
    nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * maxLabel; });

    // Update the nodes…
    var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
        .data(nodes, function(d){ 
            return d.id || (d.id = ++i); 
        });

    // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
    var nodeEnter = node.enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function(d){ return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
        //.on("click", click);
        
        
var nodeWidth = 300, nodeHeight = 100;
var buttonWidth = nodeWidth/3;

//container
nodeEnter.append("rect")
 .attr('class','buttonContainer')
        .attr("width", nodeWidth)
        .attr("height", nodeHeight)
        .style("fill", 'lightsteelblue')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,'+(-nodeHeight/2)+')');
//buttonAdd
    nodeEnter.append("rect")
    .attr('class','addButton')
        .attr("width", buttonWidth)
        .attr("height", nodeHeight/1.5)
        .style("fill",'white')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + nodeHeight/6 + ','+(-nodeHeight/2 + nodeHeight/6)+')')
        .on('click', function(d){
      alert('Add Button : ' + d.name)
        console.log('addButton')
        })
        ;
        
      //buttonDelete
    nodeEnter.append("rect")
    .attr('class','deleteButton')
        .attr("width", buttonWidth)
        .attr("height", nodeHeight/1.5)
        .style("fill",'red')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (nodeWidth - buttonWidth- nodeHeight/6 )+ ','+(-nodeHeight/2 + nodeHeight/6)+')')
        .on('click', function(d){
      alert('Delete Button : ' + d.name)
        console.log('deleteButton')
        })
        ;

    nodeEnter.append("text")
        .attr("x", function(d){ 
            var spacing = computeRadius(d) + 5;
            return d.children || d._children ? -spacing : spacing; 
        })
        .attr("dy", "3")
        .attr("text-anchor", function(d){ return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
        .text(function(d){ return d.name; })
        .style("fill-opacity", 0);

    // Transition nodes to their new position.
    var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

    nodeUpdate.select("circle")
        .attr("r", function(d){ return computeRadius(d); })
        .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

    nodeUpdate.select("text").style("fill-opacity", 1);

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
        .remove();

    nodeExit.select("circle").attr("r", 0);
    nodeExit.select("text").style("fill-opacity", 0);

    // Update the links…
    var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
        .data(links, function(d){ return d.target.id; });

    // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
    link.enter().insert("path", "g")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d", function(d){
            var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
            return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
        });

    // Transition links to their new position.
    link.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", diagonal);

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    link.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", function(d){
            var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
            return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
        })
        .remove();

    // Stash the old positions for transition.
    nodes.forEach(function(d){
        d.x0 = d.x;
        d.y0 = d.y;
    });
}

function computeRadius(d)
{
    if(d.children || d._children) return radius + (radius * nbEndNodes(d) / 10);
    else return radius;
}

function nbEndNodes(n)
{
    nb = 0;    
    if(n.children){
        n.children.forEach(function(c){ 
            nb += nbEndNodes(c); 
        });
    }
    else if(n._children){
        n._children.forEach(function(c){ 
            nb += nbEndNodes(c); 
        });
    }
    else nb++;
    
    return nb;
}

function click(d)
{
    if (d.children){
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
    } 
    else{
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
    }
    update(d);
}

function collapse(d){
    if (d.children){
        d._children = d.children;
        d._children.forEach(collapse);
        d.children = null;
    }
}

update(root);
```

```css
html{
    font: 10px sans-serif;
}

svg{
    border: 1px solid silver;
}

.node{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.node circle{
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link{
    fill: none;
    stroke: lightgray;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id=tree></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @thisOneGuy

Comment: Concept is very much fine but I am not able to include the button or icons on ever node. What you have shown is adding a box @thisOneGuy

Comment: i dont understand what you mean ? In your vis you have nodes (which are rectangles). I have nodes(rectangles), and buttons(also rectangles with click events). All you need to do, like I have done, is create a container and append all the elements of the nodes to that container; i.e, add the node (rectangle) the buttons and icons etc